# Google Apps Script Gets All Emails In Thread Not Only Labeled

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have the following code in my script:

```
function getEmail() {

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("parse");
var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
  for ( var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++ ) {
  var msg = messages[j].getBody();
  Logger.log(msg);
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

When no emails with label, everything is fine.
But if new email arriving and gets label "parse", there are all emails inside messages array, not just the one with label.
I have the same code in another account and everything works perfect.

Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Because the `Rule` you have to label the incoming email will label the hole `thread`.  Maybe it helps to switch off the gmail setting `conversation view`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error.  I created a new label and assigned it to one email in my inbox.  The script only finds that one thread.  How are you assigning the label?

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue. Possibly the problem could be related to how you are assigning the labels to the messages or a Gmail setting. I would recommend [adding the labels manually](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cmove-a-message-to-another-label) or check your Gmail settings, otherwise if you have a Google Workspace account I would suggest [contacting for support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) to see if they can assist on checking the settings for you.

Comment: I'm assigning the label by rule "Subject includes". 
I also added the label manually and had the same issue.
There is no problem in email account with adding and removing labels. 
threads[i].removeLabel(label) works as it should

Comment: conversation view is off

Comment: I tried search threads by search query "label: parse". not worked